# MongoDB let variable not working in pipeline aggregation

Tags: database, mongodb, variables, pipeline, let

Hi I am trying to use a variable that I defined in let to be used in the match lookup, but it returns no results when regex is used:

It works like this:

```
db.MSP_Prosper.aggregate([
    { $match: {Cleavage_score: {$gte:0.7}}},
    { $lookup: {
      from:"Uniprot_New_Entries",
      let: { order_item: new RegExp('.*' + "P62258" + '.*')},
      pipeline: [{
        $match: { Uniprot_AC : new RegExp('.*' + "P62258" + '.*')                                      
      }},
      { $project: { _id: 0,
        test: "$$order_item",
        date: { name: "$Uniprot_ID",
        date: "$Min_Max_Of_the_Ft_chain"} 
      }
    }],
       as:"cleavage_sites"
    }   
 }
```

])

but not when I try to use same variable defined in let function:

```
db.MSP_Prosper.aggregate([
    {$match: {Cleavage_score: {$gte:0.7}}},
    {
    $lookup: { from:"Uniprot_New_Entries",
           let: { order_item: new RegExp('.*' + "P62258" + '.*')},
           pipeline: [
             { $match: 
               { Uniprot_AC : "$$order_item" }
             },
             { $project: { _id: 0,
                  test: "$$order_item",
                  date: { name: "$Uniprot_ID",
                          date: "$Min_Max_Of_the_Ft_chain"} 
             }},    
           ],
           as:"cleavage_sites"
    }   
  }
])
```

> Ultimatelly I want to replcae the "P62258" with a local variable
>   $Protein_ID

Hope you can help,
Have tried out everything with no success.

Comment: So for each document in the `MSP_Propsper` collection that has a score above 0.7, you want to attach every document from `Uniprot_New_Entries` that contains "P62258"?  If the string "P62258" is coming from the original document, refer to it by field name in the `let`, and build the regex in an $expr in the match.

Comment: Hi Joe, Yes I want to attach every document that contains the P62258. This variable will be changing all the time as it will be a variable that comes from the MSP_Propsper collection with a variable name $Protein. Just for the sake of easy er explanation I have hard coded the P62258. But somehow mongoDB doesnt let me use the variable in the match regex when defined by the let function.

Comment: `new Regexp` is evaluated in the client before the query is sent to the mongod node, so it's value can't possibly change based on a document in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks! The answers here helped.

Comment: Having the exact same issue without regex. Works in any other than $match but fails in $match

Answer (score 1):

The `new RegExp` is evaluated in the client and included in the query as an absolute value, so you cannot include a document-dependent variable that way.

To use a document field as a regular expression inside of a lookup pipeline, you will need to use a `$expr` clause with the `$regexMatch` aggregation operator.  Note that the `.*` before and after the search string are implied, and therefore unnecessary.

Something like:

```
db.MSP_Prosper.aggregate([
  { $match: { Cleavage_score: { $gte: 0.7 } } },
  { $lookup: {
      from: "Uniprot_New_Entries",
      let: { "order_item": "$Protein_ID" },
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {
            $expr: {
              $regexMatch: {
                input: "$Uniprot_AC",
                regex: "$$order_item"
        }}}},
        {$project: {
            _id: 0,
            test: "$$order_item",
            date: {
              name: "$Uniprot_ID",
              date: "$Min_Max_Of_the_Ft_chain"
        }}},
      ],
      as: "cleavage_sites"
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mDGGRS4jYm5)

Comment: `regex: "$$order_item"` works but `regex: "$$order_item.*"` doesn't. Do you have idea about this?

Comment: `"$$order_item.*"` is ambiguous.  It could mean "the field `order_item` followed by any character string", or it could mean "The field `*` of the subdocument contained in the `order_item` field".  You might try using `{$concat:["$$order_item",".*"]}` to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue when using variable inside $match:
Was using it like this inside $match

```
dateFrom: {
  $lte: '$$coverageFrom',
},
```

this failed to work as `$$coverageFrom` was not getting the value.

Solved it like this:

```
$expr: {
    $lte: ["dateFrom", "$$coverageFrom"]
}
```

Hope this helps.